# Redirection page is not working in filter when the request raised from ajax call?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, session, filter

I am using spring filter to redirect to login page when the session got expired . It works well and good with page refresh call, but I am having an upload option in my application which is an ajax call.
When an user clicks on the upload button its not redirecting to login page once session expired. Why can it be?

Please help out with your valuable suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax then i don't think the page will redirect as you are making partial call. 
Better way to do this will be, when you ajax call doesn't return desired value and it seems that session is expired refresh the page using javascript part only. Below is code

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Tried this but no use when the session got expired the page is not executed fully i.e., the ajax call is not completing.

Comment: I'm not experienced with spring filter but i guess some where you must be checking if the session expired. so if(session==null) write 1 or 0 or whatever in response stream get that in ajax code checking it using if clause of javascript and then redirect

Comment: That is the problem am getting everything in my filter but the redirection is not working in filter . I am using response.sendRidrect() this one is not working when I initiated the ajax call after sesion expired.

Comment: i added another comment see that if that helps

Answer (score 0):

In Java script

```
//Add here Your Ajax call
//post ajax call
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
      if(var==1) //checking if response is 1. I'll return 1 if session expires else whatever data makes sense
      {
        location.reload();
      }
      else
      {
            // do stuff you'll do if session exists
      }
    }
  }
```

In Java Part

```
if(request.getSession()==null)
  {
        response.getOutputStream().print("1");
  }
  else
  {
    //do required stuffs
  }
```